# Recover MySQL database from data folder without ibdata1

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, recover, data-files

My WAMP directory accidentally get deleted by another user. Only data folder in MySQLis available. And, in that only database-folders (folders in "\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\" with name of databases) are available. **Other files** including "**ibdata1**" in root of "\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\" are also deleted.

The database folder contains files with below extensions

*.frm, *.ibd

and "db.opt" file.

How the databases can be recovered?

Comment: Try using file recovery software

Comment: I tried to recover bdata1. But, unable to get it back.

Comment: Are you trying to recover MYISAM databases or INNODB?

Comment: Both MYISAM and INNODB.

Comment: I am **still  waiting** for any support/reply which can help me to recover my @MySQL data.

Comment: I get my solution from here :
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files